# advanceby unaviable to advance an index by offer in swift 3

Tags: swift3

My project issue in screenshort.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLJcs.png)

Comment: What's your question? Add image here, not thru link.

Comment: swift 3 code issue .     original?.insert("-", at: (original?.startIndex.advancedBy(4))!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just do what the error says and use `index(_:at:offsetBy:)`:

```
original.insert("-", at: original.index(original.startIndex, offsetBy: 14))
```

In Swift 3 string handling methods have been renamed a little. `advanceBy` turned into this `offsetBy` instead.

Comment: Swift 3 issue .  No member is longCharacterIsMember          var originalText = self.mCardNumberTxtFld.text! as String
            let replacementText = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
            
            //Verify entered text is a numeric value
            let digits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
            for char in replacementText.unicodeScalars
            {
                if !digits.longCharacterIsMember(char.value)
                {
                    return false
                }
            }

Comment: command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11 swift 3